# Create list of given length with given values - convert histogram to list of values

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a histogram which I need to convert into a list of individual instances for another piece of software I am using: If I have four hits for a value of "1" and three hits for a value of "2" then my list would need to read `[1,1,1,1,2,2,2]`.

My histogram is structured as two numpy arrays packed into a list called `hist`, say. The array in `hist[1]` stores my bin edges, the array in `hist[0]` stores the counts for each bin.

A very crude way of achieving this conversion would be to simply run the following code:

```
inhist=[]
for i in range(len(hist[0])):
   for j in xrange(int(hist[0][i])):
       inhist.append(int(hist[1][i]))
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Particularly as the histogram gets very large this will presumably not be the most efficient way of achieving this anymore. Seeing as I know precisely how many time I want a certain value I wonder if I could save myself all that looping?

I realise doing this whole thing in general will eat RAM and isn't terribly efficient but, alas, I have little choice at the moment.

EDIT:
`print hist` returns:

```
[array([  0.00000000e+00,   1.83413630e+07,   1.74493106e+09,
          7.91390628e+10,   4.54474023e+11,   5.38810039e+11,
          3.01718080e+11,   1.38440761e+11,   6.17865624e+10,
          2.77457730e+10,   1.32412328e+10,   6.71579967e+09,
          3.35556066e+09,   2.00513046e+09,   1.18435261e+09,
          7.34440685e+08,   5.13846805e+08,   3.97894623e+08,
          1.97770421e+08,   1.11546165e+08,   6.63624300e+07,
          3.93196820e+07,   2.81038760e+07,   1.87733930e+07,
          1.57307950e+07,   1.55162030e+07,   1.38710060e+07,
          3.52969100e+06,   2.32881000e+05,   5.32210000e+04,
          1.59100000e+04,   4.89700000e+03,   1.61300000e+03,
          6.54000000e+02,   2.63000000e+02,   1.08000000e+02,
          3.10000000e+01,   8.00000000e+00,   4.00000000e+00,
          2.00000000e+00]),
 array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
        17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
        34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], dtype=uint64)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Those `i` indices are basically range of elements ranging for the length of number of `hist[0]` elements repeated by the numbers present in that first array `hist[0]` itself. Using those we simply index into the second array `hist[1]` to give us the desired output. For the `repeat` part, we could use [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html).

So, we would have an implementation, like so -

```
inhist = hist[1][np.arange(len(hist[0])).repeat(hist[0])]
```

Being a vectorized solution that avoids appending elements off NumPy arrays, this should be pretty efficient.

Also, if we are working with NumPy arrays of floating point numbers, we might need to convert to `int` dtype. So, feed in `hist[0].astype(int)` and if the output is needed as `int` dtype too, use the same conversion on it, like so -

```
inhist = hist[1][np.arange(len(hist[0])).repeat(hist[0].astype(int))]
```

Comment: I currently get the error `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`. Could you modify the code to show the `hist[0].astype(int)` bit?

Comment: @P-M Updated the post.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. I now get a memory error though:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path_length_distribution.py", line 24, in <module>
    inhist = hist[1][np.arange(len(hist[0])).repeat(hist[0].astype(int))]
MemoryError`
Any thoughts why?

Comment: @P-M Did you run your original code on those inputs? Did you get any such memory error then?

Comment: The original code is currently running happily. Well I presume it is, it is taking very long but I am not getting any errors.

Comment: @P-M Could you tell me the output for : `hist[0].astype(int).sum()`?

Comment: That would be the cause of the error. It gives -1480163727. Summing up all the values gives a value too large to be held in an integer (see edit of my post).